# JqueryUi DatePicker - Disable days in different months

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to show a calendar with some days enabled, my problem is, if the days are in different months, works only in the first month like 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XXq8.png)

days 1 and 2 in december would have to be enabled too.

```
/*arrayDaysToshow is my array with the dates to show in calendar*/
$('#schedulingCalendar').datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 2,
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    beforeShowDay: function(date){
                        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', date);
                        return [ $.inArray(string, arrayDaysToshow) >= 0 ]
                    },
                    onSelect: function(){
                        debugger;
                        $("#panelCalendar").animate({'height': '150px'}, 100);
                    }
                });
```

[jsfiddle exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/b73bmn3e/2/)

Comment: post a jsfiddle

Comment: @Rooster added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code in the jsfiddle actually works, the issue is actually just that the dates at the beginning of december don't have leading zero's .  So the quickest solution is to just take the leading 0 off.

Working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b73bmn3e/6/

Basically,

Instead of this:

```
var arrayDaysToshow = ["30-11-2017", "01-12-2017", "02-12-2017"];
```

Do this:

```
var arrayDaysToshow = ["30-11-2017", "1-12-2017", "2-12-2017"];
```

Or add some code to your `beforeShowDay` handler to handle the presence or lack of leading zeros in the month and day parts of dates.  Its really up to you how you want to handle the problem now that you know what it is :)

Cheers